# Network Issues and Slow Throughput

Tags: networking, internet, latency

### Background

I worked as a Customer Service Technician at a DSL Provider, when DSL was the "new technology," so I'm approaching the Problem below from that perspective.

### Problem

**Note**:  I've moved this from the Network Engineering Exchange.  This question deals with the outside topology.  If you have no idea what that mens, please don't answer.

This may be the wrong exchange, if it is, please move it.  I'm connected to home internet, using a cable provider and a customer owned [Surfboard SPG-6782-AC](https://arris.secure.force.com/consumers/ConsumerProductDetail?p=a0ha000000GNcsoAAD&c=Discontinued) DOCSIS 3.0 modem/router combo.  I know this is a discontinued model, but there is no use in upgrading until after this is solved. The internet here has been passable since I've had it, but it has never worked great. I'm posting this post using it. The issue was partly masked because it only got worse after I removed Cable TV

1. In an effort to decrease the cost of entertainment, I had the cable company remove the Cable TV and added DISH TV.  I'm still paying for Internet and Phone.
2. The Internet and modem stay connected with a decibel level of one.  The cable technician said the range was supposed to be between -10 and +10.  It was -12 until he removed all the signal splitters for Cable TV
3. DISH connects all their devices via MoCA for DVR and TV, with all boxes connected to the modem wirelessly.  I can supply the lease table if needed.
4. My ROKU and our Smart TV's all connect fine, all be it EXTREMELY SLOW
5. The Apps in all the satellite equipment never connect.  I suspect a Timeout due to latency(caused by attenuation).

Consider the following table:

```
+---------------------------------+------------+
|            Location             |  Distance  |
+---------------------------------+------------+
| Pole/Alley                      | -          |
| Drop to NID(Buried Cable)       | 250-300 FT |
| CPE/ARRIS Surfboard SBG 6782-AC | -          |
+---------------------------------+------------+
```

The backyard is huge.  All services would stop working if it rained.  In an effort to solve that, the cable company buried the line.  The drop falls, buries and rises into the NID.  For about 7 years, I always thought our deadspots were caused by an old house and a crappy radio transmitter in the modem.  After removing Cable TV, I'm beginning to wonder if it's just a severe case of signal attenuation, causing average throughput with high ping?

### Help

- Who's at fault here?  DISH claims it's the cable company, and trying
  to get a straight answer from the cable company is near impossible.
- Since I believe the cable length is too long, what are my options?  The cable company won't move the pole, but they said they can possibly move the Tap. Unless I'm misunderstanding what the tap is(the connection from the pole to the drop), how is moving it going to solve anything, as the distance in the backyard stays constant?
- Is a slower Fiber to the Premises connection better than a faster half functioning connection(100Mbps cable vs 75Mbps fiber)
- Is fiber affected by loop length/distance?

### Update

[image]

Comment: Where does the "75Mbps" for fiber come from? Is that the available plan from ISP, or some unusual technical limitation?

Comment: I don't believe there is a docsis 3.0 network In existence where those signal levels would be acceptable. Log into the modem, let us know what the modem transceiver is reporting for SNR up/down please. It's usually reachable @192.168.100.1

Comment: @grawity  I called Earthlink.  The CSR took my address and zip code, and the 75Mbps was the plan offered.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart See Image.  It was easier to capture than type.

Comment: how about your upstream signal? BTW, who is the ISP?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Grande Communications. I’ll add that.upstream picture for clarity, but Channels 5 and 6 are 42.0 and Channel 7 is 42.8. FWIW, I called today and they closed the network ticket so the agent I got got an earful and opened a new ticket.  I did hear him say that my levels at the pole weren’t great